# What's the meaning of 「〜どんなに抵抗しようとも限り…」

Tags: grammar, jlpt, volitional-form

I cannot find any material relating to this grammar point. Give the following example, could you explain what the meaning of this grammar is?

> どんなに抵抗しようとも限り生きている人はいつかは死ぬ。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence is invalid. That 限り shouldn't be there. Remove it and the sentence becomes grammatical:

> どんなに抵抗しようとも生きている人はいつかは死ぬ。(However much they may resist, living humans must eventually die.)

Or, if 限り should be used at all, it ought to be placed after 生きている.

> どんなに抵抗しようとも生きている限り人はいつかは死ぬ。(However much they may resist, as long as they are alive humans are bound to die eventually. )

Here's the rundown on the constructions in question.

・Verb(masu-stem) Phrase + **ようとも**... → **even if** S VP, ...

・**どんなに** + Verb(masu-stem) Phrase + **ようとも**, ... → **however much** S VP, ...

・Verb(adnominal) Phrase + **限り**, ... → **as long as** S VP, ....

These conversions are not as precise as they could be, but I hope they are good enough to convey the general idea.

Comment: What is the meaning of しようともhere? Or maybe additional literal meaning would help. Since a natural translations its a bit hard to learn from. thanks btw :)

Comment: どんなに…しようとも means "no matter how you do ...". しようとも alone means "even if you (should) do ...".

Comment: @Alice28 I had completely forgotten the explanation part! That was the main point of the question wasn't it? How remiss of me. I've added a sort-of exposition. Thanks for the reminder!