# Can't understand どんなに変わっていこうと笑い飛ばしてよ

Tags: translation, volitional-form

I have already passed N2 exam, but I can't understand this sentence...

> どんなに変わっていこうと笑い飛ばしてよ

Please laugh away by "どんなに Let's change it" ??
It doesn't make much sense??

Comment: I am not really sure if 変わっていこう here mean "Let's change it" or "let's be different"

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34504/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32966/9831

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is from L'Arc～en～Ciel's "I'm so happy" lyrics

> どうやら つけが廻ってきたようだ
>    あるもの全て好きにすればいいさ
>    それでもあなたよ どうか悲しまないで
>    **どんなに変わっていこうと笑い飛ばしてよ**

To understand it, I think it would help to include the previous line too. With this context I would say it means

> But you, don't be sad
>   **Keep laughing no matter how much things change**

The 変わっていこうと is the volitional form of 変わっていく, but that doesn't necessarily mean that it means "let's do" something, it can also be used of inanimate things.
For example, in the sentence
`技術がどんなに優れようと、素人は素人に過ぎない`
`No matter how good their technique is, amateurs are still amateurs`
the subject is technique.

Comment: It sounds like it has similar meaning to どんなに変わっても笑い飛ばしてよ　? Do you have any grammar reference on this usage of  volitional form? I want to learn more about it. I always thought volitional form implies some kind of "intention" of the speaker, so it's weird to see it used with inanimate things.

Comment: http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8-you-gayou-to/       This one??

Comment: That's the one! Since I'm not a grammarian, I'm not sure if "volitional" is technically the correct term. I just know that it follows the same rules of conjugation.