# Volitional form describing a noun?

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics, volitional-form

I came across this construction

> 与えよう春

in a song recently and can't quite figure out the meaning and grammar behind it. The entire stanza for reference:

> 歌声が消えようと
> 幾度と
> 想いが途絶えようと
> 与えよう春を
> 繰り返す愛を
> 心を吹き込む口付けと永遠を

Also, am I right in interpreting the "歌声が消えようと" part as basically equivalent to "歌声が消えても" (and the other similarly structured line in the same manner)? If so, how does the "幾度と" play into this all?

Comment: Duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34504/45489

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right in thinking that 歌声が消えようと means 歌声が消えても.

幾度と～～ようと means 何度～～ても "no matter how many times..."
幾度と想いが途絶えようと means 何度想いが途絶えても.

与えよう春を is an inversion/anastrophe (倒置) of 春を与えよう.
繰り返す愛を and 心を吹き込む口付けと永遠を are also the objects of 与えよう.

The stanza basically means...

歌声が消えても、何度想いが途絶えても、
春を与えよう、繰り返す愛を与えよう、心を吹き込む口付けと永遠を与えよう。